# Embedded Mono: Creating / marshaling a C# struct in C++

Tags: c#, c++, mono, mono-embedding

I'm working on an application that's embedding Mono, and I have a simple C# struct that is one of the parameters to one of my functions.

How do I create and pass that struct from C++ to C#?

If I have a C# struct like so:

```
 struct CSStruct
 {
     int mInt;
     float mFloat;
 }
```

Can I create a strict C++ version and pass it to mono like so?

```
struct CStruct
{
    int mInt;
    float mFloat;
}

// ...
CStruct var = { 10, 30.0f };
void* args[1] = { &var };
mono_runtime_invoke(method, NULL, args, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the way it's supposed to work: value types are passed in the arguments array
in mono_runtime_invoke () by taking the pointer to the value type data.